# Is there any way I can store multiple int's from a user input into a vector?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to store multiple int into a vector by having the user input the grade they have received. However I do believe there is a more simplified version of trying to do this. Would it be better to have separate functions? Is there anyone who can guide me in the right direction?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
using namespace std; 

int main() {
  cout << "Welcome to the Grade Calculator! \n"
       << "What is the student's full name? ";
  string student_name;
  getline(cin,student_name);
  cout << "\nPlease input the points earned for each assignment.";
  
  vector<int> student_grades(8); 
    cout << "\nLab 2: ";
    cin >> student_grades[0];
    cout << "Lab 3: ";
    cin >> student_grades[1];
    cout << "Lab 4: ";
    cin >> student_grades[2];
    cout << "Lab 5: ";
    cin >> student_grades[3];
    cout << "Lab 6: ";
    cin >> student_grades[4];
    cout << "Lab 7: ";
    cin >> student_grades[5];
    cout << "Lab 8: ";
    cin >> student_grades[6];
    cout << "Lab 9: ";
    cin >> student_grades[7];
    cout << "Lab 10: ";
    cin >> student_grades[8];
    
  //Finding sum of the grades
  int sum_of_grades = accumulate(student_grades.begin(),student_grades.end(),0);
  //Console Output
  cout << '\n'<< student_name << " has earned " << sum_of_grades << " points in the course, so far." << endl;
  cout << "\nThere are 2000 points possible in this course." << endl;
  cout << "\nInput the anticpated score for the final project (200 points possible): ";
  int anticipated_score;
  cin >> anticipated_score;
  int total_score = sum_of_grades+anticipated_score;
  cout << "Total Projected Assignment Points: " << total_score << endl;
  
  cout << "\nFinal Exam Score Needed for Final Course Grade (1000 Points Possible)"
       << "\nTo Earn an A, need at least: " << 1800 - total_score << " points, for a total of: 1800"
       << "\nTo Earn a B, need at least: " << 1600 - total_score << " points, for a total of: 1600"
       << "\nTo Earn a C, need at least: " << 1400 - total_score << " points, for a total of: 1400"
       << "\n To Earn a D, need at least: " << 1200 - total_score << " points, for a total of: 1200" << endl;
       
  return 0;

}
```

Comment: Beware that `student_grades[8]` is one past the end of the vector.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for-loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 8; ++i){
    cout << "\nLab " << i+2 << ": ";
    cin >> student_grades[i];
}
```

This code is essentially equivalent to what you wrote in your program; it loops through all possible indices, prompting the user to input numbers into the `vector`.

Comment: How do i display which lab grade it is asking for

Comment: @MarkRodriguez I made a trivial change to the answer to make it closer to your original.

Comment: Avoid magic numbers. `8` can be `student_grades.size()`.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: Your development environment should have come with a debugger, and if it didn't get rid of that piece of crap and get an environment that does have a debugger. Use the debugger to step through the loop and see where the extra line is coming from. It will probably be from pressing enter on the keyboard to send the input to the program.